# Angular 2 I need to know when my url starts with

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

in AngularJS when i want to know if my actually url starts with "/routing" for example, i use route-segment and i can call $routeSegment.startsWith("routing"):

```
$scope.routing = function() {

    return $routeSegment.startsWith("routing");
};
```

and then i use ng-class in HTML

```
<li ng-class="{ 'active': routing() }"></li>
```

Now, i want to do the same in Angular 2, what can i use for do this?basically i want to know the url, and then with ngClass i can active the link of bootstrap

Thanks, I'm beginner with Angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `location` service,

```
export class Foo {
   constructor(private _location: Location) {}
   routing () {
      const pattern = /^(routing)/;
      return pattern.test(this._location.path());
   }
}
```

Here I'm using a regex to match `location.path()`, but you can take another approach to matching the URL if you'd like.

Comment: I'm going to try it, thanks!!if i have any problem i will ask here again.

Comment: @Skurt Sure thing! If this does in fact answer your question, please mark it as answered so that others can find it easier. :)